# How to add a row to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, how do you add a new row to a data frame once the data frame has already been initialized?

So far I have this:

```r
df <- data.frame("hi", "bye")
names(df) <- c("hello", "goodbye")

#I am trying to add "hola" and "ciao" as a new row
de <- data.frame("hola", "ciao")

merge(df, de) # Adds to the same row as new columns

# Unfortunately, I couldn't find an rbind() solution that wouldn't give me an error
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: assign names to `de` too. `names(de) <- c("hello","goodbye")` and `rbind`

Comment: Or in one line `rbind(df, setNames(de, names(df)))`

Comment: This really is an area which base R fails miserably at, and has for a long time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599197/rbind-data-frames-without-names

Comment: @thelatemail disagree. data frames are a special structure in r. a list of lists with common dimnames and attributes and methods. I think it is very expected that one cannot `rbind(data.frame(a = 1), data.frame(b = 2))`.. why would you want to? I would hope that would throw an error regardless. It's like `merge`'ing with a random `by` variable. And this is 2015, doesn't everyone set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`?

Comment: @rawr - sure, different names shouldn't be bound, but R can't handle binding no names to no names, binding names to no names with the same dimensions, or binding new data to incorporate new factor levels. I think that's a weakness. Particularly when it can handle binding repeated names and all NA names. And setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` can be a quick fix, but changing the defaults that other people are going to have set differently can really ruin a day.

Comment: @thelatemail again, rbinding is akin to cbinding. you *would not*, or I should say *should not*, be cbinding data frames. merging explicitly cbinds by a common by variable. it is dangerous to cbind blindly as it should be to rbind blindly. And IMO adding factor levels is not straight-forward, as it should not be, because it is an unusual operation. How often do you need to add a level to sex or race? It's just a level of error checking to me. And I'm not sure what you mean by no names to no names--arent we still talking about data frames here?

Comment: Just use the "split" command:
[split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6tJe.png)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Like @Khashaa and @Richard Scriven point out in comments, you have to set consistent column names for all the data frames you want to append.

Hence, you need to explicitly declare the columns names for the second data frame, `de`, then use `rbind()`. You only set column names for the first data frame, `df`:

```
df<-data.frame("hi","bye")
names(df)<-c("hello","goodbye")

de<-data.frame("hola","ciao")
names(de)<-c("hello","goodbye")

newdf <- rbind(df, de)
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to fix this if I dont have a second dataframe declared, but instead have each value I want to add to a new row stored as a variable?

Comment: Try: `newdf<-rbind(df, data.frame(hello="hola", goodbye="ciao"))` OR with variable: `newdf<-rbind(df, data.frame(hello=var1, goodbye=var2))`

Answer (score 206):

Let's make it simple:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("v1","v2")
```

Comment: This causes problems when trying to add a new row with mixed data types (some string, some numeric). In such a case, even the numeric values are converted to string. One workaround is to add the values separately, something like the following (assuming there are 3 columns): `df[nrow(df) + 1, 1:2] = c("v1", "v2")` and `df[nrow(df), 3] = 100` But still it's a good point about adding new row. So, +1

Comment: Or use "list" instead of "c".

Comment: nice idea, but how can I do if I want to insert or add a new row a the first position?

Comment: @Matheus Araujo: Is this the most efficient way to add row to a df? I have 100k+ rows to be added in a loop. Feel like nrow would get slower as number of rows increase.

Comment: @ChintanPathak, to be honest, I don't know if using nrow() is very naive (I'm open to suggestion).  However, I know that if you know the size of your final data.frame and if you allocate it in memory before populating it, the action will be faster.

Comment: Tried this with data.table but tells with nrow+1 is out of range.

Comment: @Arani there's already an answer with `list()`. I reverted your edit.

Answer (score 87):

There's now `add_row()` from the `tibble` or `tidyverse` packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% add_row(hello = "hola", goodbye = "ciao")
```

Unspecified columns get an `NA`.

Comment: I liked this approach if you stick to the tidyverse philosophy. 
Otherwise basic R syntax is a survival skill that comes in handy when you are in an environment where you don't have privileges to import packages.
I particularly like the answer using plain R syntax with `rbind` and `as.matrix` [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467834/1585486)

Comment: Just I'd like to mention that the library is dplyr.

Comment: @Ariel To be specific, yes. But it's usually going to just be "tidyverse" to load anything else that you might want.

Comment: If it is already in a data frame, you can do: `df1 %>% add_row(df2)`. If there are multiple rows in `df2` they will also be appended. @Ariel `add_row` is imported by `dplyr`.

Answer (score 62):

Or, as inspired by @MatheusAraujo:

`df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list("v1","v2")`

This would allow for mixed data types.

Answer (score 25):

I like `list` instead of `c` because it handles mixed data types better.  Adding an additional column to the original poster's question:

```
#Create an empty data frame
df <- data.frame(hello=character(), goodbye=character(), volume=double())
de <- list(hello="hi", goodbye="bye", volume=3.0)
df = rbind(df,de, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
de <- list(hello="hola", goodbye="ciao", volume=13.1)
df = rbind(df,de, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Note that some additional control is required if the string/factor conversion is important.

Or using the original variables with the solution from MatheusAraujo/Ytsen de Boer:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list(hello="hallo",goodbye="auf wiedersehen", volume=20.2)
```

Note that this solution doesn't work well with the strings unless there is existing data in the dataframe.

Comment: If `hello` and `goodbye` are in character in `df`, you can do the following. You do not necessarily use names in a list. `df <- data.frame(hello = "hi", goodbye = "bye", volume = 1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE); rbind(df, list("hola", "ciao", 100))`.

Answer (score 14):

Not terribly elegant, but:

```
data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(df), as.matrix(de)))
```

From documentation of the `rbind` function:

> For `rbind` column names are taken from the first argument with appropriate names: colnames for a matrix...

Comment: This solution works without needing to specify the columns to add, which is much better for applications on large datasets

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make an empty data frame and add contents in a loop, the following may help:

```r
# Number of students in class
student.count <- 36

# Gather data about the students
student.age <- sample(14:17, size = student.count, replace = TRUE)
student.gender <- sample(c('male', 'female'), size = student.count, replace = TRUE)
student.marks <- sample(46:97, size = student.count, replace = TRUE)

# Create empty data frame
student.data <- data.frame()

# Populate the data frame using a for loop
for (i in 1 : student.count) {
    # Get the row data
    age <- student.age[i]
    gender <- student.gender[i]
    marks <- student.marks[i]

    # Populate the row
    new.row <- data.frame(age = age, gender = gender, marks = marks)

    # Add the row
    student.data <- rbind(student.data, new.row)
}

# Print the data frame
student.data
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

To build a data.frame in a loop:

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:10){
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(str="hello", x=i, y=i*10))
}
```

Comment: I think usually for loop is something we try our best to avoid in R...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to append a record from one dataframe to another IF you know that the two dataframes share the same columns and types.  To append one row from `xx` to `yy` just do the following where `i` is the `i`'th row in `xx`.

```
yy[nrow(yy)+1,] <- xx[i,]
```

Simple as that.  No messy binds.  If you need to append all of `xx` to `yy`, then either call a loop or take advantage of R's sequence abilities and do this:

```
zz[(nrow(zz)+1):(nrow(zz)+nrow(yy)),] <- yy[1:nrow(yy),]
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the dataframe.

```
> df <- data.frame("hello"= character(0), "goodbye"=character(0))
> df
[1] hello   goodbye
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list("hi","bye")
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "hi") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "bye") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
  hello goodbye
1  <NA>    <NA>
>
```

.

```
> df <- data.frame("hello"= character(0), "goodbye"=character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> df
[1] hello   goodbye
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list("hi","bye")
> df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list("hola","ciao")
> df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list(hello="hallo",goodbye="auf wiedersehen")
> df
  hello         goodbye
1    hi             bye
2  hola            ciao
3 hallo auf wiedersehen
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make certain to specify
`stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the dataframe:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> trigonometry <- data.frame(character(0), numeric(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> colnames(trigonometry) <- c("theta", "sin.theta")
> trigonometry
[1] theta     sin.theta
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> trigonometry[nrow(trigonometry) + 1, ] <- c("0", sin(0))
> trigonometry[nrow(trigonometry) + 1, ] <- c("pi/2", sin(pi/2))
> trigonometry
  theta sin.theta
1     0         0
2  pi/2         1
> typeof(trigonometry)
[1] "list"
> class(trigonometry)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Failing to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the dataframe will
result in the following error when attempting to add the new row:

```
> trigonometry[nrow(trigonometry) + 1, ] <- c("0", sin(0))
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 1):

To formalize what someone else used setNames for:

```
add_row <- function(original_data, new_vals_list){ 
  # appends row to dataset while assuming new vals are ordered and classed appropriately. 
  # new_vals must be a list not a single vector. 
  rbind(
    original_data,
    setNames(data.frame(new_vals_list), colnames(original_data))
    )
  }
```

It preserves class when legal and passes errors elsewhere.

```
m <- mtcars[ ,1:3]
m$cyl <- as.factor(m$cyl)
str(m)

#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

Factor preserved when adding 4, even though it was passed as a numeric.

```
str(add_row(m, list(20,4,160)))
#'data.frame':  33 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ... 
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

Attempting to pass a non- 4,6,8 would return an error that factor level is invalid.

```
str(add_row(m, list(20,3,160)))
# 'data.frame': 33 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 3) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 1):

I think,

```
rbind.data.frame(df, de)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the tidyverse, this is commonly done with `bind_rows`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(hello = "hi", goodbye = "bye")
df2 <- data.frame(hello = "hola", goodbye = "ciao")

library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

---

In dplyr >= 1.0.0 you *could* use [`row_insert`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) (though probably overkill for this situation):

```
df1 %>% 
  rows_insert(df2)
Matching, by = "hello"
  hello goodbye
1    hi     bye
2  hola    ciao
```

**Note**: all columns in `df2` must exist in `df1`, but not all columns in `df1` have to be in `df2`.

For additional behavior, there are other `row_*` options. For example, you could use `row_upsert` which will overwrite the values if they exist already, otherwise it will insert them:

```
df2 <- data.frame(hello = c("hi", "hola"), goodbye = c("goodbye", "ciao"))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  rows_upsert(df2)
Matching, by = "hello"
  hello goodbye
1    hi goodbye # bye updated to goodbye since "hi" was already in data frame
2  hola    ciao # inserted because "hola" was not in the data frame
```

These functions work by matching key columns. If the `by` argument is not specified then the default behavior is to match the first column in the second data frame (`df2` in this example) to the first data frame (`df1` in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Building on prior answers, new rows can be added to a data frame using replacement functions. Replacement functions can encapsulate code complexity, which is advantageous when row additions are occurring multiple times in the same code.

Multiple versions of such a function are presented in order of increasing complexity.

**Version 1**: This version is like the answers by @MatheusAraujo or @YtsendeBoer. It is compact and useful if all column data for the new row is present in a fixed order.

```
'new_row<-'<- function(x, value){x[nrow(x) + 1,] <- value; x}

 df <- data.frame(A = 1,  B = 2,  C = 3)
 new_row(df) <- c(4,  5,  6)
 new_row(df) <- list(7,  8,  9)
```

**Version 2**: Though slightly longer, this version improves traceability by keying new data to the column name. All named columns must be present, though not necessarily in order, when adding a new row.

```
'new_row<-'<- function(x, value){
    x[nrow(x) + 1,] <- sapply(names(x), function(y){value[y]}); x
 }

 df <- data.frame(A = 1,  B = 2,  C = 3)
 new_row(df) <- c(B = 1, C = 2,  A = 3)     
 new_row(df) <- list(C = 1,  A = 2,  B = 3)
 new_row(df) <- data.frame(A = 3,  B = 4,  C = 5)
```

**Version 3:** This bulkier version will work when columns are missing and when new named columns are included. This is advantageous when new rows need adding while column data is still incomplete or when new rows only partially fit the data frame.

```
'new_row<-'<- function(x, value){
  x[names(value)[!is.element(names(value), names(x))]] <- numeric()
  x[nrow(x) + 1,] <- sapply(names(x), function(y){
    if(is.element(y,names(value))){return(value[y])}else{return(NA)}
  }); x}  

df <- data.frame(A = 1,  B = 2,  C = 3)

new_row(df) <- NA
new_row(df) <- c(A = 5)
new_row(df) <- list(C = 1,  A = 2, B = 1)
new_row(df) <- data.frame(Z = 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add to the other suggestions.
I use the base r code to create a dataframe:

```
data_set_name <- data.frame(data_set)
```

Now I always suggest making a duplicate of the original data frame just in case you need to go back or test something out. I listed that below:

```
data_set_name_copy <- data_set_name
```

Now if you wanted to add a new column the code would look like the following:

```
data_set_name_copy$Name_of_New_Column <- Data_for_New_Column
```

The `$` signifies that you are adding a new column and right after as outlined you insert the nomenclature/name for your new entry.