# Adding additional Rows to DF

Tags: r, r-rownames

I have a completed working script, however i would like to add additional rows to the script. Same error happens in colnames additions

adding the new ones & redirecting to fresh sheet

```
colnames(main)<-c("Company","Mapped","Not.Mapped","Pending")
rownames(main)<-c("CompA","CompB","CompC")

write.table(main, file="Main.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE)
```

Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length

output should look like the below

````
Company Mapped  Not.Mapped  Pending X.Mapped  
CompA   190     19          63      90.91%  
CompB                 
CompC   66      9           36      88.00%```
````

Comment: You are changing the column and row names with these calls. Not adding new rows to a data.frame.

Comment: it seemed to work the first time i created this script. How would i add new rows, and how come it worked previously? Thanks Phiver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add row to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467068/add-row-to-dataframe)

Comment: See link to duplicate. I don't think it worked previously as you expected it to work.

Comment: i want to change the row names, by adding "CompB" in as a new static row. This will then give blanks on the columns (other than company) where i can info afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear at all. If you want to add a new row you can use `[]`. Note that `dim(main)[1]` returns the total rows in your current object. `dim(main)[1] + 1` indicates that you are going to add an additional row. The vector you pass must have 4 elements (or as many variables your dataframe have)

```
main[dim(main)[1] + 1,] <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Yes, `rbind` is most straightforward.