# How to append a row to a data.frame with different clumn types?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which is initially empty and then shall be filled:

```
df <- data.frame(datetime=as.POSIXct(character()), t=factor(), val=numeric())
```

Until now I could not found a solution to append rows continously to the end.

I am looking for a solution similar to this, but working of course:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(as.POSIXct('2002-02-12 22:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz='UTC'),"test", 34.5)
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add row to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467068/add-row-to-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `rbind()` + `cbind()` like below

```
df <- rbind(df, setNames(data.frame(as.POSIXct('2002-02-12 22:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz='UTC'),"test", 34.5),names(df)))
```

such that you will get

```
> df
             datetime    t  val
1 2002-02-12 22:00:00 test 34.5
```

Comment: There is also `setNames()` which can be more readable than ````colnames<-````

Comment: Thx, I am just wondering, that the datetime shows as integer and not as datetime string. What is the reason for this and how can it be changed?

Comment: @Roland I guess it is because of `cbind`... you can see my update, where `data.frame()` replaced `cbind()`