# RStudio - weird formatting to append new row to .csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to append a new row of data to an existing .csv file but everytime I do so, it doesn't add it to a new row. Instead, it just appends to the last row like so:

[image: It doesn't add below it, but next to it]

Also, the first column is supposed to show the date but I'm not sure why it shows up as hashtags. But in the column where it shows 33882020-09-24, it should end at 3388 and everything else after that should be in their respective column below.

Here is what I have for my code. I've followed multiple forums on how to append to .csv files and did exactly what was shown so I am at a loss..

[image: R code example]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: As.character should help. I guess you need to share at least part of your csv. E.g. as gist in github.

Comment: Do you have more columns in `x` than what you have in `test` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I'm actually reading and writing into the same .csv file if that helps. In this example, I only did one row for `x` to test it out and use as an example

Comment: @Christoph how would you use as.character for this example?

Answer (score 1):

For the data, is possible that the Rstudio don't recognise the number as a data (because you use -, and for R is a operation. Try don't use this symbol, but for example_) or try to write 24sept2020.
For add a new row a found this info:
[How can a add a row to a data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467068/how-can-a-add-a-row-to-a-data-frame-in-r)